# I can't complete registration on ru.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts, unregistered-users, sign-up

I have tried many times to complete my registration, but I'm still unregistered.

The account with my email  on openid.stackexchange.com does not exist.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Looks like your Russian SO account isn't marked as Registered correctly. A developer can fix this for you in a few seconds once they stumble upon this.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that. (cc @animuson)